# A phrase for "prove with document"

Tags: phrase-request

Someone wrote:

> In this book Cooper **proves with documents** that the US and Europe had a big role in the overthrow of the Shah and the rise of this new regime.

As I searched by Google, I found no result for "prove with document".

What is the phrase in English?

Answer (score 2):

In legal terms, one would generally use the phrase **[documentary evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentary_evidence)** to describe evidence in the form of documents. Using your example:

> In this book Cooper **provides documentary evidence** that the US and
>   Europe had a big role in the overthrow of the Shah and the rise of
>   this new regime.

Comment: How about "*In this book Cooper provides documents that prove that the US and Europe...*"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the simple expression

> In this book Cooper ***documents*** how the US and Europe had a big role in the overthrow of the Shah and the rise of this new regime.

since the evidence is presented by Cooper.

Comment: Thanks, I look for an idiomatic phrase for "prove with document" like "prove through/based on documents"...as a type of *proof* which convey  both "prove" and "document"...

Comment: "documented proof" it doesn't mean "paper" documents, it means "evidence", "documents" is the verb which is "to explain given the evidence" as in a "documentary" that one watches on TV.